# Which brand made clone bricks with "HL" on the studs?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

This brand also copied some of the original lego sets such as 8418, 8150, and 8151(weirdly its colored in red rather than blue)

I don't need you to identify what's this part is, i just wanna know the brand's name

[image]

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything with HL or with 7H. Is it possible the writing is Cyrillic?

Comment: Could be, i don't know either

Comment: I tried to search a bit with 7H in cyrillic but did not find anything (and there is no letter looking like L in cyrillic)

Comment: It's "HL" then. This quite hard tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question, twice. But i finally found it. It was Brick Intellect, but why the name on the stud was "HL" instead of "BI/BL" or "BT" as it show on to picture where the B and T are marked red
[image]